# gitlab api get group list only 20 groups not all

Tags: curl, gitlab

We use Gitlab 7.8, i'm trying to get full list of groups on our prod server via gitlab api, unfortunately gitlab api is returning only 20 groups out of 80 available group. Any help in this would be appreciated.

```
command used is curl -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token of admin users"  https://server_name/api/v3/groups
```

Running this as admin and adding admin account to all the groups didn't help either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

20 is the [default number of results returned by GitLab API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/README.md#pagination)

You could pass the `per_page=80` parameter, to get your 80 expected groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i still run into the same. Now i use command used is curl -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token of admin users"   --header "per_page=100" https://server_name/api/v3/groups

Comment: @maestromani maybe because of a bug similar to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7492 and https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/9048/files?

Comment: Okay I think this means I have to update my gitlab installation first. Running 7.8.2 and passing 80 instead of 100 doesn´t work for me

Comment: the thing is, `per_page` IS NOT A HEADER. It is just a query param

Comment: @Nebulosar Good point. It is not a header indeed.

Answer (score 6):

As well as the 'per_page=100' I would also recommend using 'page=' also, if you have more repositories than the maximum value of per_page. You can specify a maximum per_page value of 100.

Something like `curl -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token of admin users"  https://server_name/api/v3/groups?page=1&per_page=100`

Comment: Hi Dante, Thanks a lot for this clarification, however I have a follow up question, how to get 2nd page users if you have more than 1 pages? because on first page only 100 results are displayed

Comment: Hi Sunny. Sure. It's page=2&per_page=100

Comment: Question still remains, how do u get all ur output w/out knowing the item/page count in advance.

Comment: You have to use pagination with the GitLab API to get complete results beyond the max page size. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination

Also note that if you have projects organised into subgroups, the Group List Projects API has an include_subgroups option (default false) that will need to be provided if you also want to list projects contained in subgroups. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects

Comment: You can also follow nandeesh's answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197424/4220286