# Gitlab API for all projects under group

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to get a list of all the projects which are under a particular group in Gitlab. Here is the example scenario:

Group A (id: 1) has 3 Project

> Group A / Project 1
>
> Group A / Project 2
>
> Group A / Project 3

Group B (id: 2) has 5 Projects

> Group B / Project 1
>
> Group B / Project 2
>
> Group B / Project 3
>
> Group B / Project 4
>
> Group B / Project 5

Now if I hit the rest api `GET /groups` it will give me only the list of groups. If i hit the rest api `GET /projects/all`, it will give me a list of all the projects.

What I am looking for, is an operation something like `GET /groups/:groupid/projects/all`

That is: all the projects for that particular group. Like if I say `GET /groups/1/projects/all` it will give me `Project 1, Project 2 and Project 3`.

The only way I can think of is to get a list of all the projects and loop over them to see if it matches my group name, but this will be lot of unnecessary  parsing.

How can I achieve this in a better way?

I am working on Gitlab CE 7.2.1. I am referring the [Gitlab API documententation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking to do something similar, getting all of the projects from a number of groups.

There are 2 ways of doing this that I can see, depending on how much info you know about the group and how dynamic you need it to be.

**Option 1**

If you know the IDs of the groups that you need, then you can get the group by ID and that will provide you with the projects

```rb
projects = Gitlab.group(group_id).projects
```

**Option 2**

If you don't know the group IDs or need to be able to pass in group names more dynamically, you will need to make an extra call to get all of the groups, loop through them and get the individual groups. This may not be any better than your original idea of looping over all of the projects, depends on how many groups / projects you have

```rb
groups = []
Gitlab.groups.each do |group|
  if ['your_group_name', 'another_group_name'].include? group.name
    groups << Gitlab.group(group.id)
  end
end

projects = []
groups.each do |group|
  projects << group.projects
end
```

I am by no means an expert Ruby programmer, so there are no doubt far better ways of achieving this or improving the code, but this worked for my needs as it only needed to be run occasionally so speed was not an issue for me

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the recently released [Gitlab GraphQL API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/) to query groups by name :

```graphql
{
  group(fullPath: "your_group_here") {
    projects {
      nodes {
        name
        description
        httpUrlToRepo
        nameWithNamespace
        starCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can go to the following URL : https://[your_gitlab_host]/-/graphql-explorer and past the above query

The Graphql endpoint is a POST on "https://$gitlab_url/api/graphql"
An example using `curl` and `jq`:

```bash
gitlab_url=<your gitlab host>
access_token=<your access token>
group_name=<your group>

curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ group(fullPath: \"'$group_name'\") { projects {nodes { name description httpUrlToRepo nameWithNamespace starCount}}}}"
      }' "https://$gitlab_url/api/graphql" | jq '.'
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding to @Dante's answer,

This gives first 20 projects in the group.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://gitlab.your_namespace.com/api/v4/groups/your_group_id/projects
```

To get more projects we should add 'page' and 'per_page' parameter.

The below request will fetch you up to 100 projects under requested group.

```
 curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://gitlab.your_namespace.com/api/v4/groups/your_group_id/projects?&per_page=100" .
```

If you now want all projects, you have to loop through the pages.
Change the page parameter.

Add json_pp to your request to get a nicely formatted output.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://gitlab.your_namespace.com/api/v4/groups/your_group_id/projects | json_pp
```

Answer (score 10):

This is fairly handy if you use `curl`:

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" http://gitlab.your_namespace.com/api/v4/groups/your_group/projects
```

Answer (score 7):

adding to Betrands answer on GraphQL. You can see all subgroups by using query below.

```
{
  group(fullPath: "**your_group_here**") {
    projects (includeSubgroups: true){
      nodes {
        name
        description
        archived
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tested on Gitlab 8.0. Its group API can provide the project list under a specific group. Just send the GET request to `http://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/groups/[group_id]?private_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx`  with your private token.

For example: `http://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/groups/3?private_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

In the JSON response, the list is an array under `projects` key.